# how to make my loop fixed depending on the array elements| C++

Tags: c++

I have an array and a for loop. I want the for loop to stop depending on the number of elements the array has.

For example if I have an `int array []={1,0,1,0,1}`
I want the loop to execute code 5 times. Similar to the function for strings .length() but for integers. An example with a simple code would be the best answer :)

> like this pseudocode:

```
for(int b=0;b<array-length;b++)
```

Comment: `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` will evaluate to the number of elements in the array.

Comment: ^^ Provided it's not decayed to a pointer of course. `std::array` or a range based for loop as in the answers are probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need the index, the following works fine:

```
int ar[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (auto i : ar) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged with C++, I'll have to suggest `std::vector` as the best solution. (Also for the future)

Look into this: [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

So for you this'd be like the following:

```
std::vector<int> array {1,0,1,0,1};
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
   ...
```

Or in the worst case an `std::array` if you don't want the features of a vector.

See also: [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: I thought of it as I wrote this, added it just now as you put it!

Comment: that sounds like good, do I need to include any libraries? because I get error

Comment: Yes you need <vector> for vector and <array> for array.

Answer (score 0):

To find length of an array, use this code

```
int array[5];
std::cout << "Length of array = " << (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)) << std::endl;
```

So in your case, it will be for example:

```
int array[5];
for(int b=0; b < sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); b++){
   std::cout << array[b] << std::endl;
}
```